# Is there a way to select an unselect multiple buttons with hover effect?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a sort of chatbot in HTML, CSS, and javascript with the website here > https://chatroombot.n8thedev.repl.co/

If you click the menu button you will find a page to change the background, so far hovering over the 27 different buttons creates a border inside the button that is somewhat transparent. I attempted to make a click effect where it makes the clicked button border darker (higher alpha value). The issue I ran into was when I cleared the other borders when you click on the button. EX: if (Click button 1) { border: none for button 1,2,3... }

But when I tried to do that the hover effect didn't work anymore because it cleared the button's border permanently.

I am here for suggestions on a solution.

Also here is the existing code:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>CHAT!!</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
 
<body>
    <script src="script.js" defer>
 
    </script>
    <div class="chatBoxContainer" id="chatBoxContainer" style="">
 
    </div>
    <div class="entryMessage">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="inputBg" id="inputBg"></div>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Type a message" autocomplete="off" class="inputMessage" id="inputMessage" onkeypress="return demoForEnterKey(event)" style="font-size: 16px;" onclick="this.style.color='white';"></input> 
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="menuButton" id="menuButton" style= "cursor:pointer" onclick="menuClick()">
    <img src="menu.png" class="menuButtonImage"></img>
  </button>
  <div class="newScreen" id="newScreen">
    <div class="colorSelectorTitle">
      <div>
        <div class="backText">Set Chat Wallpaper</div>
        <button class="backButton" style="background-color: transparent; border-style: none; cursor: pointer;" onclick="bringBack()">
          <img src="back-arrow.png" class="backArrowImg"></img>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="backgroundChooserContainer">
      <div class="backgroundSelector">
        <button class="_3sW34" id="clr1" style="background-color: rgb(5, 5, 5);">
          <span class="defaultText">Default</span>
        </button>
        <button class="_3sW34" style="background-color: rgb(15, 36, 36);" id="clr2"></button>
        <button class="_3sW34" style="background-color: rgb(18, 38, 31);" id="clr3"></button>
        <button class="_3sW34" style="background-color: rgb(17, 36, 28);" id="clr4"></button>
        <button class="_3sW34" style="background-color: rgb(17, 30, 39);" id="clr5"></button>
        <button class="_3sW34" style="background-color: rgb(15, 34, 36);" id="clr6"></button>
        <button class="_3sW34" style="background-color: rgb(31, 29, 37);" id="clr7"></button>
        <button class="_3sW34" style="background-color: rgb(33, 33, 33);" id="clr8"></button>
        <button class="_3sW34" style="background-color: rgb(31, 33, 28);" id="clr9"></button>
        <button class="_3sW34" style="background-color: rgb(35, 35, 27);" id="clr10"></button>
        <button class="_3sW34" style="background-color: rgb(38, 36, 25);" id="clr11"></button>
        <button class="_3sW34" style="background-color: rgb(38, 31, 23);" id="clr12"></button>
        <button class="_3sW34" style="background-color: rgb(38, 23, 23);" id="clr13"></button>
        <button class="_3sW34" style="background-color: rgb(38, 15, 16);" id="clr14"></button>
        <button class="_3sW34" style="background-color: rgb(38, 10, 16);" id="clr15"></button>
        <button class="_3sW34" style="background-color: rgb(25, 5, 11);" id="clr16"></button>
        <button class="_3sW34" style="background-color: rgb(33, 16, 12);" id="clr17"></button>
        <button class="_3sW34" style="background-color: rgb(15, 12, 12);" id="clr18"></button>
        <button class="_3sW34" style="background-color: rgb(16, 25, 25);" id="clr19"></button>
        <button class="_3sW34" style="background-color: rgb(10, 29, 37);" id="clr20"></button>
        <button class="_3sW34" style="background-color: rgb(13, 21, 35);" id="clr21"></button>
        <button class="_3sW34" style="background-color: rgb(13, 15, 17);" id="clr22"></button>
        <button class="_3sW34" style="background-color: rgb(10, 12, 13);" id="clr23"></button>
        <button class="_3sW34" style="background-color: rgb(17, 11, 18);" id="clr24"></button>
        <button class="_3sW34" style="background-color: rgb(30, 31, 31);" id="clr25"></button>
        <button class="_3sW34" style="background-color: rgb(38, 38, 24);" id="clr26"></button>
        <button class="_3sW34" style="background-color: rgb(35, 35, 31);" id="clr27"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

script.js:

```
var txt = document.getElementById("inputMessage");
var newScreen = document.getElementById("newScreen");
newScreen.style.display = "none";
 
window.onload = function () {
  var chatBoxHeight = window.innerHeight - 80;
  var realChatBoxHeight = chatBoxHeight + "px";
  var chatBox = document.getElementById("chatBoxContainer").style.height = realChatBoxHeight;
}
 
window.onresize = function () {
  var chatBoxHeight = window.innerHeight - 80;
  var realChatBoxHeight = chatBoxHeight + "px";
  var chatBox = document.getElementById("chatBoxContainer").style.height = realChatBoxHeight;
}
 
function bringBack() {
  newScreen.style.display = "none";
}
 
function createBotChat (botChatText) {
  var chatContainer = document.getElementById("chatBoxContainer");
  var newBotChat = document.createElement("div");
  newBotChat.className = "newBotChat";
  newBotChat.textContent = botChatText;
  chatContainer.appendChild(newBotChat);
  newBotChat.scrollIntoView();
}
 
function demoForEnterKey(eventName) {
  if (eventName.keyCode == 13 && document.getElementById("inputMessage").value != "") {
    var txt = document.getElementById("inputMessage");
    var newChat = document.createElement("div");
    newChat.textContent = txt.value + "                   ";
    var chatContainer = document.getElementById("chatBoxContainer");
    newChat.className = "newChat";
    var timeStamp = document.createElement("div");
    timeStamp.className = "timeStamp";
    var today = new Date();
    var hour = today.getHours();
    var min;
    var amOrPm;
    if (today.getHours() > 24 && today.getHours() < 13) {
      amOrPm = "AM";
    } else {
      amOrPm = "PM";
    }
    if (hour == 13){
      hour = 1;
    } else if (hour ==14){
      hour = 2;
    }
    else if (hour == 15){
      hour = 3;
    }
    else if (hour == 16){
      hour = 4;
    }
    else if (hour == 17){
      hour = 5;
    }
    else if (hour == 18){
      hour = 6;
    }
    else if (hour == 19){
      hour = 7;
    }
    else if (hour == 20){
      hour = 8;
    }
    else if (hour == 21){
      hour = 9;
    }
    else if (hour == 22){
      hour = 9;
    }
    else if (hour == 23){
      hour = 10;
    }
    else if (hour == 24){
      hour = 11;
    }
    else if (hour == 1){
      hour = 12;
    }
    if (today.getMinutes() == 0){
      min = "00";
    } else if (today.getMinutes() == 1){
      min = "01";
    }
    else if (today.getMinutes() == 2){
      min = "02";
    }
    else if (today.getMinutes() == 3){
      min = "03";
    }
    else if (today.getMinutes() == 4){
      min = "04";
    }
    else if (today.getMinutes() == 5){
      min = "05";
    }
    else if (today.getMinutes() == 6){
      min = "06";
    }
    else if (today.getMinutes() == 7){
      min = "07";
    }
    else if (today.getMinutes() == 8){
      min = "08";
    }
    else if (today.getMinutes() == 9){
      min = "09";
    } else if (today.getMinutes() > 9) {
      min = today.getMinutes();
    }
    timeStamp.textContent = hour + ":" + min + " " + amOrPm;
    newChat.appendChild(timeStamp);
    chatContainer.appendChild(newChat);
    newChat.scrollIntoView();
    if (newChat.textContent.toLowerCase().includes("help") == true) {
      createBotChat("List of all commands:");
      createBotChat("• Clear - Clears the previous chats" + "\n" +" • Website - Displays our main page" + "\n" + "")
    } else if(newChat.textContent.toLowerCase().includes("clear") == true) {
      location.reload();
    } else if(newChat.textContent.toLowerCase().includes("website") == true) {
      createBotChat("Our website: example.com")
    }
    document.getElementById("inputMessage").value = "";
  }
}
 
createBotChat("Welcome to N8TheDev's ✨NEW✨ chatroom bot!!");
createBotChat("Type 'Help' to see a list of all the  bots's commands");
 
function menuClick () {
  newScreen.style.display = "block";
}
```

style.css:

```
body{
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
 
.newScreen {
  background-color: #1E2428;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
 
.menuButtonImage {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
 
.backArrowImg {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  filter: invert(100%);
}
 
.backText {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  left: 85px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 19px;
  font-family: Segoe UI,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Lucida Grande,Arial,Ubuntu,Cantarell,Fira Sans,sans-serif;
}
 
.backButton{
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
 
.colorSelectorTitle {
  background-color: #323739;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 60px;
  height: 15%;
  max-height: 80px;
}
 
.menuButton {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: transparent;
  top: 15px;
  border-style: hidden; 
  right: 15px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
 
.entryMessage {
  background: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 62px;
  width: 100%;
}
 
.container{
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}
 
.inputMessage{
  border-color: transparent;
  background: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 96%;
  height: 30px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: white;
}
 
.inputBg{
  border-radius: 50px 50px 50px 50px;
  border-color: transparent;
  background: #33383B;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 99%;
  height: 43px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
 
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
  color: #818486;
}
::-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 19+ */
  color: #818486;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* IE 10+ */
  color: #818486;
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
  color: #818486;
}
 
textarea:focus, input:focus{
outline: none;
}
 
.chatBoxContainer {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: transparent;
}
 
.newBotChat {
  text-align: left;
  color: lightgray;
  font-family: Segoe UI,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Lucida Grande,Arial,Ubuntu,Cantarell,Fira Sans,sans-serif;
  white-space: pre-line;
  background-color: #3b4044;
  width: max-content;
  max-width: 60%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 4px 6px 4px 6px;
  margin: 7px 0px 7px 0px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  word-wrap: normal;
}
 
.newChat {
  text-align: left;
  color: lightgray;
  font-family: Segoe UI,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Lucida Grande,Arial,Ubuntu,Cantarell,Fira Sans,sans-serif;
  background-color: #1d6f70;
  width: max-content;
  max-width: 60%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 4px 6px 4px 6px;
  margin: 7px 0px 7px 0px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
 
* {
  scrollbar-color: rgba(0,0,0,.2) hsla(0,0%,100%,.1);
  scrollbar-width: thin;
}
 
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 6px!important;
  height: 6px!important;
}
 
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}
 
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: hsla(0,0%,100%,.1);
}
 
.timeStamp {
  color: #f1f1f2a1;
  position: relative;
  flex: none;
  font-size: 11px;
  line-height: 19px;
  display: inline-block;
}
 
 ._2brEy {
  background-color: #0d1418;
}
 
 ._2RSZp {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  position: relative;
}
 
._3sW34 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 82px;
  height: 82px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 4px solid transparent;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
 
.defaultText {
  text-align: center;
  color: lightgray;
  font-family: Segoe UI,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Lucida Grande,Arial,Ubuntu,Cantarell,Fira Sans,sans-serif;
  max-height: 72px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
 
._3sW34:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 4px solid rgba(225, 225, 225, 0.2);
}
 
.backgroundChooserContainer {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 75%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: transparent;
  margin: 10px;
}
 
.backgroundSelector {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 60%;
}
 
html, body {
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Please include existing code as text here on Stack Overflow, not just on an external website were it may be deleted at any time. Stack Overflow exists to house questions that many people will have, and therefore need to stand the test of time. See [ask] for more tips on how to create questions that are less likely to be downvoted and closed.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thx for the info just updated it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should avoid using inline style as much as possible.
Practically all styling can be done in CSS
So instead of removing the border from all other boxes, you could add another class (i.e `active`) to the clicked box:

```
._3sW34.active {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 4px solid rgba(225, 225, 225, 1);
}
```

This would require remove that class from all other boxes.

Or even simple use of `:focus` selector

```
._3sW34:focus {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 4px solid rgba(225, 225, 225, 1);
}
```

Another more lengtly approach is to set clicked box index in it's parent as an attribute, then in CSS you can use something like this:

```js
var txt = document.getElementById("inputMessage");
var newScreen = document.getElementById("newScreen");
newScreen.style.display = "none";
 
window.onload = function () {
  var chatBoxHeight = window.innerHeight - 80;
  var realChatBoxHeight = chatBoxHeight + "px";
  var chatBox = document.getElementById("chatBoxContainer").style.height = realChatBoxHeight;
}
 
window.onresize = function () {
  var chatBoxHeight = window.innerHeight - 80;
  var realChatBoxHeight = chatBoxHeight + "px";
  var chatBox = document.getElementById("chatBoxContainer").style.height = realChatBoxHeight;
}
 
function bringBack() {
  newScreen.style.display = "none";
}
 
function createBotChat (botChatText) {
  var chatContainer = document.getElementById("chatBoxContainer");
  var newBotChat = document.createElement("div");
  newBotChat.className = "newBotChat";
  newBotChat.textContent = botChatText;
  chatContainer.appendChild(newBotChat);
  newBotChat.scrollIntoView();
}
 
function demoForEnterKey(eventName) {
  if (eventName.keyCode == 13 && document.getElementById("inputMessage").value != "") {
    var txt = document.getElementById("inputMessage");
    var newChat = document.createElement("div");
    newChat.textContent = txt.value + "                   ";
    var chatContainer = document.getElementById("chatBoxContainer");
    newChat.className = "newChat";
    var timeStamp = document.createElement("div");
    timeStamp.className = "timeStamp";
    var today = new Date();
    var hour = today.getHours();
    var min;
    var amOrPm;
    if (today.getHours() > 24 && today.getHours() < 13) {
      amOrPm = "AM";
    } else {
      amOrPm = "PM";
    }
    if (hour == 13){
      hour = 1;
    } else if (hour ==14){
      hour = 2;
    }
    else if (hour == 15){
      hour = 3;
    }
    else if (hour == 16){
      hour = 4;
    }
    else if (hour == 17){
      hour = 5;
    }
    else if (hour == 18){
      hour = 6;
    }
    else if (hour == 19){
      hour = 7;
    }
    else if (hour == 20){
      hour = 8;
    }
    else if (hour == 21){
      hour = 9;
    }
    else if (hour == 22){
      hour = 9;
    }
    else if (hour == 23){
      hour = 10;
    }
    else if (hour == 24){
      hour = 11;
    }
    else if (hour == 1){
      hour = 12;
    }
    if (today.getMinutes() == 0){
      min = "00";
    } else if (today.getMinutes() == 1){
      min = "01";
    }
    else if (today.getMinutes() == 2){
      min = "02";
    }
    else if (today.getMinutes() == 3){
      min = "03";
    }
    else if (today.getMinutes() == 4){
      min = "04";
    }
    else if (today.getMinutes() == 5){
      min = "05";
    }
    else if (today.getMinutes() == 6){
      min = "06";
    }
    else if (today.getMinutes() == 7){
      min = "07";
    }
    else if (today.getMinutes() == 8){
      min = "08";
    }
    else if (today.getMinutes() == 9){
      min = "09";
    } else if (today.getMinutes() > 9) {
      min = today.getMinutes();
    }
    timeStamp.textContent = hour + ":" + min + " " + amOrPm;
    newChat.appendChild(timeStamp);
    chatContainer.appendChild(newChat);
    newChat.scrollIntoView();
    if (newChat.textContent.toLowerCase().includes("help") == true) {
      createBotChat("List of all commands:");
      createBotChat("• Clear - Clears the previous chats" + "\n" +" • Website - Displays our main page" + "\n" + "")
    } else if(newChat.textContent.toLowerCase().includes("clear") == true) {
      location.reload();
    } else if(newChat.textContent.toLowerCase().includes("website") == true) {
      createBotChat("Our website: example.com")
    }
    document.getElementById("inputMessage").value = "";
  }
}
 
createBotChat("Welcome to N8TheDev's ✨NEW✨ chatroom bot!!");
createBotChat("Type 'Help' to see a list of all the  bots's commands");
 
function menuClick () {
  newScreen.style.display = "block";
}



function findNode(node, cl)
{
  if (!node || !node.classList)
    return null;
  if (node.classList.contains(cl))
    return node;
  return findNode(node.parentNode, cl);
}

const bgSelector = document.querySelector(".backgroundSelector");
bgSelector.addEventListener("click", e => 
{
  let button = findNode(e.target, "_3sW34");
  if (!button)
    return;

  bgSelector.setAttribute("active", [].indexOf.call(button.parentNode.children, button) + 1);
});
```

```css
body{
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
 
.newScreen {
  background-color: #1E2428;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
 
.menuButtonImage {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
 
.backArrowImg {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  filter: invert(100%);
}
 
.backText {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  left: 85px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 19px;
  font-family: Segoe UI,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Lucida Grande,Arial,Ubuntu,Cantarell,Fira Sans,sans-serif;
}
 
.backButton{
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
 
.colorSelectorTitle {
  background-color: #323739;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 60px;
  height: 15%;
  max-height: 80px;
}
 
.menuButton {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: transparent;
  top: 15px;
  border-style: hidden; 
  right: 15px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
 
.entryMessage {
  background: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 62px;
  width: 100%;
}
 
.container{
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}
 
.inputMessage{
  border-color: transparent;
  background: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 96%;
  height: 30px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: white;
}
 
.inputBg{
  border-radius: 50px 50px 50px 50px;
  border-color: transparent;
  background: #33383B;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 99%;
  height: 43px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
 
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
  color: #818486;
}
::-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 19+ */
  color: #818486;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* IE 10+ */
  color: #818486;
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
  color: #818486;
}
 
textarea:focus, input:focus{
outline: none;
}
 
.chatBoxContainer {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: transparent;
}
 
.newBotChat {
  text-align: left;
  color: lightgray;
  font-family: Segoe UI,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Lucida Grande,Arial,Ubuntu,Cantarell,Fira Sans,sans-serif;
  white-space: pre-line;
  background-color: #3b4044;
  width: max-content;
  max-width: 60%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 4px 6px 4px 6px;
  margin: 7px 0px 7px 0px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  word-wrap: normal;
}
 
.newChat {
  text-align: left;
  color: lightgray;
  font-family: Segoe UI,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Lucida Grande,Arial,Ubuntu,Cantarell,Fira Sans,sans-serif;
  background-color: #1d6f70;
  width: max-content;
  max-width: 60%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 4px 6px 4px 6px;
  margin: 7px 0px 7px 0px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
 
* {
  scrollbar-color: rgba(0,0,0,.2) hsla(0,0%,100%,.1);
  scrollbar-width: thin;
}
 
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 6px!important;
  height: 6px!important;
}
 
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}
 
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: hsla(0,0%,100%,.1);
}
 
.timeStamp {
  color: #f1f1f2a1;
  position: relative;
  flex: none;
  font-size: 11px;
  line-height: 19px;
  display: inline-block;
}
 
 ._2brEy {
  background-color: #0d1418;
}
 
 ._2RSZp {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  position: relative;
}
 
._3sW34 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 82px;
  height: 82px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 4px solid transparent;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
 
.defaultText {
  text-align: center;
  color: lightgray;
  font-family: Segoe UI,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Lucida Grande,Arial,Ubuntu,Cantarell,Fira Sans,sans-serif;
  max-height: 72px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
 
._3sW34:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 4px solid rgba(225, 225, 225, 0.2);
}
 
.backgroundChooserContainer {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 75%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: transparent;
  margin: 10px;
}
 
.backgroundSelector {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 60%;
}
 
html, body {
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}


.backgroundSelector[active="1"] > ._3sW34:nth-child(1),
.backgroundSelector[active="2"] > ._3sW34:nth-child(2),
.backgroundSelector[active="3"] > ._3sW34:nth-child(3),
.backgroundSelector[active="4"] > ._3sW34:nth-child(4),
.backgroundSelector[active="5"] > ._3sW34:nth-child(5),
.backgroundSelector[active="6"] > ._3sW34:nth-child(6),
.backgroundSelector[active="7"] > ._3sW34:nth-child(7),
.backgroundSelector[active="8"] > ._3sW34:nth-child(8),
.backgroundSelector[active="9"] > ._3sW34:nth-child(9),
.backgroundSelector[active="10"] > ._3sW34:nth-child(10),
.backgroundSelector[active="11"] > ._3sW34:nth-child(11),
.backgroundSelector[active="12"] > ._3sW34:nth-child(12),
.backgroundSelector[active="13"] > ._3sW34:nth-child(13),
.backgroundSelector[active="14"] > ._3sW34:nth-child(14),
.backgroundSelector[active="15"] > ._3sW34:nth-child(15),
.backgroundSelector[active="16"] > ._3sW34:nth-child(16),
.backgroundSelector[active="17"] > ._3sW34:nth-child(17),
.backgroundSelector[active="18"] > ._3sW34:nth-child(18),
.backgroundSelector[active="19"] > ._3sW34:nth-child(19),
.backgroundSelector[active="20"] > ._3sW34:nth-child(20),
.backgroundSelector[active="21"] > ._3sW34:nth-child(21),
.backgroundSelector[active="22"] > ._3sW34:nth-child(22),
.backgroundSelector[active="23"] > ._3sW34:nth-child(23),
.backgroundSelector[active="24"] > ._3sW34:nth-child(24),
.backgroundSelector[active="25"] > ._3sW34:nth-child(25),
.backgroundSelector[active="26"] > ._3sW34:nth-child(26),
.backgroundSelector[active="27"] > ._3sW34:nth-child(27)
{
  border: 4px solid rgba(225, 225, 225, 1);
}
```

```html
    <div class="chatBoxContainer" id="chatBoxContainer" style="">
 
    </div>
    <div class="entryMessage">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="inputBg" id="inputBg"></div>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Type a message" autocomplete="off" class="inputMessage" id="inputMessage" onkeypress="return demoForEnterKey(event)" style="font-size: 16px;" onclick="this.style.color='white';"></input> 
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="menuButton" id="menuButton" style= "cursor:pointer" onclick="menuClick()">
    <img src="menu.png" class="menuButtonImage"></img>
  </button>
  <div class="newScreen" id="newScreen">
    <div class="colorSelectorTitle">
      <div>
        <div class="backText">Set Chat Wallpaper</div>
        <button class="backButton" style="background-color: transparent; border-style: none; cursor: pointer;" onclick="bringBack()">
          <img src="back-arrow.png" class="backArrowImg"></img>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="backgroundChooserContainer">
      <div class="backgroundSelector">
        <button class="_3sW34" id="clr1" style="background-color: rgb(5, 5, 5);">
          <span class="defaultText">Default</span>
        </button>
        <button class="_3sW34" style="background-color: rgb(15, 36, 36);" id="clr2"></button>
        <button class="_3sW34" style="background-color: rgb(18, 38, 31);" id="clr3"></button>
        <button class="_3sW34" style="background-color: rgb(17, 36, 28);" id="clr4"></button>
        <button class="_3sW34" style="background-color: rgb(17, 30, 39);" id="clr5"></button>
        <button class="_3sW34" style="background-color: rgb(15, 34, 36);" id="clr6"></button>
        <button class="_3sW34" style="background-color: rgb(31, 29, 37);" id="clr7"></button>
        <button class="_3sW34" style="background-color: rgb(33, 33, 33);" id="clr8"></button>
        <button class="_3sW34" style="background-color: rgb(31, 33, 28);" id="clr9"></button>
        <button class="_3sW34" style="background-color: rgb(35, 35, 27);" id="clr10"></button>
        <button class="_3sW34" style="background-color: rgb(38, 36, 25);" id="clr11"></button>
        <button class="_3sW34" style="background-color: rgb(38, 31, 23);" id="clr12"></button>
        <button class="_3sW34" style="background-color: rgb(38, 23, 23);" id="clr13"></button>
        <button class="_3sW34" style="background-color: rgb(38, 15, 16);" id="clr14"></button>
        <button class="_3sW34" style="background-color: rgb(38, 10, 16);" id="clr15"></button>
        <button class="_3sW34" style="background-color: rgb(25, 5, 11);" id="clr16"></button>
        <button class="_3sW34" style="background-color: rgb(33, 16, 12);" id="clr17"></button>
        <button class="_3sW34" style="background-color: rgb(15, 12, 12);" id="clr18"></button>
        <button class="_3sW34" style="background-color: rgb(16, 25, 25);" id="clr19"></button>
        <button class="_3sW34" style="background-color: rgb(10, 29, 37);" id="clr20"></button>
        <button class="_3sW34" style="background-color: rgb(13, 21, 35);" id="clr21"></button>
        <button class="_3sW34" style="background-color: rgb(13, 15, 17);" id="clr22"></button>
        <button class="_3sW34" style="background-color: rgb(10, 12, 13);" id="clr23"></button>
        <button class="_3sW34" style="background-color: rgb(17, 11, 18);" id="clr24"></button>
        <button class="_3sW34" style="background-color: rgb(30, 31, 31);" id="clr25"></button>
        <button class="_3sW34" style="background-color: rgb(38, 38, 24);" id="clr26"></button>
        <button class="_3sW34" style="background-color: rgb(35, 35, 31);" id="clr27"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```